# How to insert combobox value into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

So I want to insert combobox value into database. The combobox value is retrieved from tbl_supplier and from that I want to insert chosen item into other table, which is tbl_product.

Here's my code:

```
     <?php
      include_once 'dbconfig.php';
      ....

    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) { //for inserting image


...

         $product_supplier = $_POST['product_supplier']; // having problem with this line, i think?

...

         $imagename=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
         $target_path = "img/".$imagename;


    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {



      $query_upload="INSERT into tbl_product(product_supplier) VALUES 
      ('$product_supplier')";
      mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  



    }else{  

       exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 

    }
```

```
 <select name="product_supplier">
                          <?php
                          $q1 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_supplier");
                          while($test = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
                            $supplier_name  = $test["supplier_name"];
                          {

                            ?>  

                            <option value="<?php echo $supplier_name?>"><?php echo $supplier_name ?> </option>
                            <?php

                            }


                          ?>
                          </select>
```

Help me, badly needed to solve this. Open for any suggestion or syntax of code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's simple, use `$_POST['product_supplier']` to get selected value after submit the form.

Comment: sorry sir, but where exactly to put that thing?

Comment: in your action file (i.e. 'foobar.php') which you define in form tag, i.e. `<form action='foobar.php' method='post'>`

Comment: still dont get the solution ...

Comment: I highly suggest you to use mysqli or PDO. Whats the error your getting. Can you please post so that we can help you out

Comment: error says 'undefined variable that address to " $product_supplier = $_POST['product_supplier'];"' .. i think, i dont get the value of combobox. Its written in one page, so I dont have any action file.

My prof using that so I dont have any choice in using PDO for now.. 
Hope you can help me to solve or suggest sir any way to get the value of combobox to insert it in the database .. TIA